# How to keep deleting cells based on their value

Tags: google-apps-script

i wanted to keep deleting cell B1 if there is no value on it.

```
  //delete Sheet Cells
  var Question1 = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
  var range = sheet.getRange("B1");
  if(Question1 == '' ){
  range.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `while` instead of `if`:

```
  var range, Question1;
  Question1 = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
  while (Question1 == '' ){
    range = sheet.getRange("B1");
    range.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.COLUMNS);    
    Question1 = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
 }
```